# How do I use `chpldoc` on GitHub

Tags: python-sphinx, chapel

When running `chpldoc` and pushing to github, the themes are corrupted.  Do I need to set a flag to allow github to insert a theme?

== UPDATE ==

A specific example is [here](https://buddha314.github.io/numsuch/) I ran this with `chpldoc src/*.chpl -o docs`

Comment: Could you elaborate more on *the themes are corrupted*?

Comment: Did you grab all the generated files when pushing to github, or just the ones that shared a name with your source files?  It looks to me like some of the other generated files are missing

Comment: do you mean `git add docs/*` ?

Comment: Yeah, I would expect that command to be sufficient

Comment: Thought I did that, let me try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an empty .nojekyll file is required, see this link:

https://daler.github.io/sphinxdoc-test/includeme.html#add-a-nojekyll-file